Python trouble recognizing when two keys are pressed I.e shift and the letter B (Ctrl + b)
I am working on a text editor program. I am having issues on getting upper case characters when Shift is pressed. I got this code awhile back on checking which key is pressed.
from tkinter import *

def fun(event):
    print(event.keysym, event.keysym=='a')
    print(event.keycode)

root = Tk()
root.bind("<KeyRelease>", fun)
root.mainloop()

The problem is if you press the Shift button and a letter, it prints the lowercase character. However if you hold the Shift key for a moment then you get the uppercase. I don't type real fast but even at my speed if I don't hesitate on the shift press or press hard it won't recognize the upper case character.
I tried my typing in word and note pad as well as the code editor I am using. No issues in any of these when using the same speed.
I also tried to import keyboard in the above small program and had the same outcome.
Any ideas?

Try binding to <KeyPress> instead of <KeyRelease>
